# How to concatenate multiple string fields into single field using MongoDB Aggregation?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Let's suppose I have an incoming data in the following format:

```
{
  "Name": "Test"
  "Location": "Whatever",
  "customerServices": [
      {
        "id": "test",
        "cusId": "test",
        "adr": "Adr 1",
        "serviceCounty": "Center",
        "area": "village"
      },
      {
        "id": "test",
        "cusId": "test",
        "adr": "adr2",
        "serviceCounty": "West",
        "area": "city"
      },
      {
        "id": "test",
        "cusId": "test",
        "adr": "test",
        "serviceCounty": "West",
        "area": "test"
      }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas, how to write an aggregation query which would:

1. Create a new field called '**serviceAreas**'. Type: list
2. For each item in the 'customerServices'. It would select: **adr**, **serviceCounty** and **area** fields.
3. Append them together into a single string and add to the newly created **serviceAreas** field.
4. It would select and do the operation only for distinct serviceCounty items

**So the end result would be like this:**

```
{
  "Name": "Test"
  "Location": "Whatever",
  "customerServices": [
      {
        "id": "test",
        "cusId": "test",
        "adr": "Adr 1",
        "serviceCounty": "Center",
        "area": "village"
      },
      {
        "id": "test",
        "cusId": "test",
        "adr": "adr2",
        "serviceCounty": "West",
        "area": "city"
      },
      {
        "id": "test",
        "cusId": "test",
        "adr": "test",
        "serviceCounty": "West",
        "area": "test"
      }
  ],
  "serviceAreas": [
       "Adr 1, Center, village", "adr2, West, city"
]
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Here is what I have tried, but it didn't work out:

```
'serviceAreas': {
    '$reduce': {
        'input': '$serviceImpactHistory.event.services',
        'initialValue': [],
        'in': {
            '$setUnion': [
                '$$value', {'$concat': ['$$this.serviceCounty', '$$this.adr', '$$this.area']}
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: You can try using the [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) operator.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But, kind of can't wrap my head around the whole thing. Tried using it along with $setUnion and $cascanate, but it doesn't seem to work. Or perhaps I am doing something wrong

Comment: Try searching the net for the usage of `$reduce`. Also, include the code you had tried so that someone can try to help and fix the issues.

Comment: Updated, the question with what I have already tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use $setUnion, just create your string with $concat

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      serviceAreas: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$customerServices",
          "initialValue": "",
          "in": {
            "$concat": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.serviceCounty",
              ", ",
              "$$this.adr",
              ", ",
              "$$this.area",
              ", "
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Try it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7TNPlRLgQ9d)